# Iterating through a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am writing some python code to iterate through a 2-dimensional array A, and prints 'negval' if there exists a negative number in the array, or prints 'positive' if not. This code generates a compiler error "'int' object is not iterable". Can someone explain this error and how to fix it?

```
A = [[0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,0]]
r,c = 0

for r in range(3):
  for c in range(3):
    if A[r][c] < 0:
      print 'negval'

print 'positive'
```

Comment: Why you are returning things? I see no `function` here.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Sorry, changed returns to prints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

The problem come from this line and you should have this traceback:

```
>>> r, c = 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-506be499ea74> in <module>()
----> 1 r, c = 0

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You try to do a list unpacking but `0` isn't a list. If you want `r` and `c` to be `0`, you could do:

```
r, c = 0, 0
# or
r = c = 0
```

2.

For iterate over your list of lists, I'll do:

```
for a, b, c in A:
    ...
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c` will be the three elements of each list.

Answer (score 1):

```
r,c = 0
```

This line won't work, that's because you are trying to unpack a value, which is not iterable. Rather do,

```
r=c=0
```

However, using `range` and that also with hardcoded number isn't a good idea. Rather use `any`:

```
print "negval" if any(element<0 for innerList in A for element in innerList) else "positive"
```

And if you are not comfortable with `any`, do this:

```
negative=False

for innerList in A:
    for element in innerList:
        if element<0:
            negative=True

print 'negval' if negative else "positive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the definition of r,c = 0 which is not needed causing the issue.
```

or

```
r, c = 0,0
```

or

```
 r = c = 0
```

Please define a function / method to looks better

**Similarly, you can use xrange function which will yield generator for an integer.**

```
def test_2d_parse_array():
    """
    """
        A = [[0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,0]]
    r = c = 0

    for r in xrange(3):
      for c in xrange(3):
        if A[r][c] < 0:
          return 'negval'

    return 'positive'
if __name__ == '__main__':
 test_2d_parse_array()
```

Comment: Edited my question to make it not a function

Comment: @user3413460 Updated answer , please check